# Программа для замены системных звуков

Tags: python, windows-10, аудио

Решил написать программу для замены звуков в windows 10 однако, возникли проблемы с правами.

Следующий код заменяет системный файл в windows, который отвечает за установку оборудования

```
 shutil.move('Windows - установлено оборудование.wav',
            r"C:\\Windows\Media\Windows - установлено оборудование.wav")
```

Пробовал получать права администратора, с помощью оборачивания кода в .exe однако нужны права trustedInstaller. Подскажите, как мне решить проблему с правами?

Comment: заместо замены файлов напрямую с борьбой trustedinstaller, рекомендую рассмотреть вариант изменения реестра по пути `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\AppEvents\Schemes\Apps\.Default` В этом разделе хранятся подразделы по событиям, под каждой из них есть `.Defualt` и `.Current`, параметром по умолчанию выступает путь к файлу `.wav`. При этом файлы можно наименовать как угодно, главное попасть в нужный ивент. Для редактирования реестра подойдет библиотека `winreg`

Comment: Большое спасибо)